# Alignment issue in navigation drawer menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Navigation drawer menu icon and menu title are not aligned in same line. The alignment is ok for all the menu but the issue comes only in the first item as shown below. And this issue comes only in nexus S device but working fine all other devices. So I couldnt find the reason

[image: Home should be aligned straight to the icon but it is moved down]

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item ></item>
    <item >Home</item>
    <item >Find People</item>
    <item >Photos</item>
    <item >Communities</item>

</string-array>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Is there a newline character before `Home`? That could be the possible reason behind it aligning like that.

Comment: Please provide some code which is relevant to your problem.

Comment: I have edited my code. For some reason I have to leave the first item as empty here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in you **drawer_list_item.xml** file the textview of the title with the below code..

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
```

If you want to change the alignment change **android:gravity="right"** (left, center etc).

Else check your Imageview...Maybe the problem caused by the dimensions of the image..

Comment: Actually it works fine in all devices. This issue comes only in 4.7" screen devices